# Change display depending on input loop range

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a list of products, some of them having a bulk discount table.
I want to display the table instead of the price then and highlighting the right entry.
The code im working on just works inconsistent and debug values are all correct. The if statement seems to be not right.
Maybe there is a better solution to loop the ranges.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    $(document).on('change','.bulk-discount-qty input',function(){
        var bd_field_v = $(this).val();
        var bd_table = $(this).parents().find('.bulk-discount');
        $(bd_table).find('.bulk-discount-fromto').each(function(){

            // undo previous highlight
            $(this).css('background-color', 'transparent');

            // Debugging values
            console.log('current-amount: ' + bd_field_v);
            console.log('data-bulk-discount-from: ' + $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-from'));
            console.log('data-bulk-discount-to: ' + $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-to'));

            if ( (bd_field_v >= $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-from')) && (bd_field_v <= $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-to'))) {
                // hightlight & stop loop when in range
                $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
                return false;
            }
        });
   });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e7432qhd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems in your code

1. you are returning false if condition matches, that means loop is not running on each element  and its not changing background color to transparent to each element.

e.g. if second condition satisfies loop exits and does not change background to transparent to third and fourth element.

To overcome this issue I have set background out of loop

2. You have to convert all your numbers to integer, currently they are string and in string your calculations won't work.

I used `Number(value)` to convert them to integer

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('change', '.bulk-discount-qty input', function() {
    var bd_field_v = $(this).val();
    var bd_table = $(this).parents().find('.bulk-discount');
    $(bd_table).find('.bulk-discount-fromto').css('background-color', 'transparent').each(function() {

      // Debugging values
      console.log('current-amount: ' + bd_field_v);
      console.log('data-bulk-discount-from: ' + $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-from'));
      console.log('data-bulk-discount-to: ' + $(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-to'));

      if ((Number(bd_field_v) >= Number($(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-from'))) && Number((bd_field_v) <= Number($(this).attr('data-bulk-discount-to')))) {
        $(this).css('background-color', '#f00');
        return false;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.display-table {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.display-table>.thead {
  display: table-header-group;
}

.display-table>.thead>.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.display-table>.thead>.row>.col {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.display-table>.tbody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.display-table>.tbody>.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.display-table>.tbody>.row>.col {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="itempart prices bulk-discount">
  <div class="owl-bulk-table display-table">
    <div class="thead">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bulk-discount-fromto" data-bulk-discount-from="1" data-bulk-discount-to="1" data-bulk-discount-amount="49" style="background-color: transparent;">1</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-fromto" data-bulk-discount-from="2" data-bulk-discount-to="6" data-bulk-discount-amount="39" style="background-color: transparent;">2-6</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-fromto" data-bulk-discount-from="7" data-bulk-discount-to="10" data-bulk-discount-amount="35" style="background-color: transparent;">7-10</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-fromto" data-bulk-discount-from="11" data-bulk-discount-to="9999" data-bulk-discount-amount="32" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">11+</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bulk-discount-amount" data-bulk-discount-from="1" data-bulk-discount-to="1" data-bulk-discount-amount="49">49€</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-amount" data-bulk-discount-from="2" data-bulk-discount-to="6" data-bulk-discount-amount="39">39€</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-amount" data-bulk-discount-from="7" data-bulk-discount-to="10" data-bulk-discount-amount="35">35€</div>
        <div class="col bulk-discount-amount" data-bulk-discount-from="11" data-bulk-discount-to="9999" data-bulk-discount-amount="32">32€</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br /><br />
<div class="itempart qtycheck bulk-discount-qty">
  <div class="quantity">
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="quantity_5ed76d1ed6158">Amount</label>
    <input type="number" id="quantity_5ed" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="" name="quantity" value="1" title="Menge" size="4" placeholder="" inputmode="numeric">
  </div>
</div>
```

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/1njvtk2z/1/

Comment: thank you very much. the string/int issue i suspected but didnt know how to fix. I used return false to stop the loop when found. Thanks it works, but do you know why 11+ is standard hightlighted?

Comment: When? At page load first time?

Comment: Yes, it should standard highlight the 1

Comment: Check your html. You have specified background color on fourth element. Perhaps you should do something like this https://jsfiddle.net/mfag218n/ What I did is wrap all your code in one function. Called that function on `document.ready` and on `change event`

Comment: oh damn, no that was cause i copied the html out of inspector while the issued js was already triggered. Thank you very much!

Comment: Your last snipped with the function outputs an error for me:  "TypeError: $ is not a function"   ->  var bd_field_v = $('.bulk-discount-qty input').val();